# Preview a link on web page in table with iframe but don't make it part of table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

So what I want to do is display in a small box the page that you get from clicking a link/button/image, like a preview of the link and I used iframe to do this but the iframe fills up the table button which I give the iframe to and shifts everything out of the way so it's all you can see.

What I want is something that is more of a kind of popup preview when the mouse hovers a button in my table that does not move other elements of the display (and kind of overlays the current page).

I was hoping to find some examples of this web feature but haven't found any code so far

Comment: Can you please provide us with what you have done already? Show us some code.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is a css modal see link for an example [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_modal.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done pretty easily with a few simple jQuery event handlers; I've done a quick example to illustrate this with a table and an iframe as you describe. Mousing over a cell in the table displays an iframe at the location the mouse first hovered the cell with a dynamic URL based on the contents of the cell hovered:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NYZXzr

Because the `iframe` is absolutely positioned and its `top` and `left` properties are set dynamically when invoked, it's appearing does not shift the contents of the `table` because the `iframe` itself is not part of the `table` markup but is outside it.

Sample code:

HMTL

```
<table id="myTable">
...(table contents)
</table>
<iframe id="myFrame" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

JS/jQuery

```
$('#myTable td').mouseenter(function(event){
  $('#myFrame').css({'top':event.pageY,'left':event.pageX}).prop('src','https://www.bing.com/search?q=' + event.target.innerText).show();
});
$('#myTable td').mouseleave(function(event){
  $('#myFrame').hide().prop('src','about:blank');
});
```

CSS

```
#myTable {
  z-index:1;
}
#myFrame {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2
}
```

The `mouseenter` handler is triggered once each time the mouse first hovers (e.g. enters) that element; in this case, any `td` (e.g. table body cell) within `#myTable`.

The handler [1] sets the `iframe` position based on the mouse coordinates of where the event was triggered (e.g. place top-left corner of the iframe where the mouse is when it hovers the table cell), [2] sets the `iframe` `src` to a dynamic URL based on the cell hovered (in this case, a Bing query with the cell contents) and [3] shows the `iframe`.

The `mouseleave` handler essentially does the reverse; hides the iframe and resets the URL of the `iframe` back to an empty page.

The key CSS you need is [1] ensure the `iframe` z-index is higher than the `table` and [2] `position:absolute` to ensure the `iframe` is displayed at the exact location per the `top` & `left` properties that are set and not relatively within the flow of the page.